# Is it possible to separate out sections of git diff a bit better?

Tags: git, git-diff

This is a typical output for `git diff`:

```
a3y3 $ git diff
diff --git a/folder1/doc.go b/folder1/doc.go
index 882hfd2..842h45f 100344
--- a/folder1/doc.go
+++ b/folder1/doc.go
@@ -1,5 +1,5 @@
 /*
-folder1 contains all of the code required for solutions that allow for the generation of test data.
+Package folder1 contains all of the code required for solutions that allow for the generation of test data.
 Generating this data is a complex process, and consists of multiple large steps.
 
diff --git a/folder2/file.go b/folder2/file.go
index bbe01dd..ed9a880 100644
--- a/folder2/file.go
+++ b/folder2/file.go
@@ -149,33 +149,47 @@ func (ts *ScenarioTransactionSet) GenerateTestData(messageList []Message
 
        // some code
```

It's pretty hard to see at a glance where these diffs begin and end, especially while scrolling through large number of diffs. Is there a way to separate out each diff for a file better, maybe add a decorator like so?

```
************************************************
* diff --git a/folder1/doc.go b/folder1/doc.go *
* index 882hfd2..842h45f 100344                *
* --- a/folder1/doc.go                         *
* +++ b/folder1/doc.go                         *
************************************************
```

Comment: There's [git difftool](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-difftool). You configure it to use a GUI tool that presents diffs nicely. These tools exist on every OS that programmers use, and some of them are really elegant and easy to use.

Comment: Also consider `git gui` and `gitk` (pre-installed with git). Both tools have slightly improved visual diffs, but none as detailed as real editors or IDEs. Might be a good compromise, you're the only judge.